# Unable to get Perl's flock working

Tags: perl, file, locking

I can't seem to make Perl's
[`flock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) work.
I'm locking a file, checking return valued to make sure it's actually locked, and I'm still able to open and write to it like nothing is the matter.

Here is how I lock the file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use Fcntl ':flock';

$| = 1;

my $f = $ARGV[0];

open( my $fh, '>>', $f ) or die "Could not open '$f' - $!";
print "locking '$f'...";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$f' - $!";
print "locked\n";

sleep 10;
print "waking up and unlocking\n";
close( $fh );
```

While that script is sleeping I can fiddle with the same text file from a different process

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $f = $ARGV[0];

open( my $fh, '>>', $f ) or die "Could not open '$f' - $!";
print $fh "This line was appended to a locked file!\n";
close( $fh );
```

Why am I then able to open the file and write to it without being told that it's locked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`flock()` is an advisory lock. You have to have all your processes using `flock()`

Also realize that the way you are calling `flock()` it will block until it can get a lock. If you want a failure you have to use the `LOCK_NB` flag as well.

```
open(my $lf, ">>fileIWantToLockOn");
my $gotLock = flock($lf, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);

unless ($gotLock)
{
    print "Couldn't get lock. Exiting";
    exit 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Also note that `flock()` won't work on NFS

Comment: Wow... not working over NFS is going to throw a serious wrench in this... I'd hoped to have a process create and lock a file. I'd then be later check the lock status of that file to see if the process had finished yet. Perhaps there's another way to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem there is even if it did work and the file was no longer locked, you don't know that the process you were waiting on completed successfully or not - you just know that it's no longer locked. For something not fancy that just works, why not just have the long running process create a file on the filesystem when it's done?

Comment: @brian: I really don't care how it finished, as long as it *did* finish. I'm writing a wrapping utility around stuff that I don't have control over... I'd planned on creating the locked file and execing my new process. I may be able wrap around the long running process with file creation at the end, but then I'd be stuck not knowing whether or not it's still running, or if it crashed...

Comment: And the two processes have to be on two different machines, eh?

Comment: Running in a cluster with SGE... they could be anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't SGE provide any facilities for that? (I've never used it). I would think you should be able to schedule jobs with dependencies.

Comment: That's not exactly what my goal is... this question came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263169/keeping-track-children-from-old-runs-of-a-script

Comment: I got nothin then, sorry. Without some sort of messaging or overseer you're kinda hosed.

Comment: The answers to that other question are pretty solid, you can do all of that with signal handling.

Comment: I've got reason to not want to do it that way, but I'll figure something out! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 8):

I don't think `flock` does what you think it does. Locking a file doesn't prevent anybody from doing anything to the file *except* trying to obtain a lock on the same file.

From `man 2 flock` on my system:

> flock(2) places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a file, a process is free to ignore the use of flock(2) and perform I/O on the file.

Answer (score 4):

`flock` works with *advisory* locks.  Among other things, this means that only other processes that try to `flock` the same file will realize it's locked.